# How to cause file stat error of "Value too large for defined data type" in Linux

Tags: linux, stat

I ran into an issue with file copy where it can not stat the file and produced the following error:

cp: can't stat '/tmp/nvram.data': Value too large for defined data type

I then lost nvram.data, but would like to reproduce this error. Is there a way that I could manually cause a file to be in that condition for stat? I read the following link which seems relevant, but didn't get any idea of how to recreate the error from it.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-1075/msgs-2215/index.html

I tried with corrupting zip files etc, but it didn't have the same effect.

Comment: The last paragraph of the link you posted explains how it usually happens. So you need to recreate that condition. It might also be possible with a removable drive that was formatted on a system with larger datatypes.